# django orm JSONField for mysql

Tags: python, mysql, json, django

I am trying to define a model with one column being a `mysql json type`. Searching on web results in suggestions related to django's `postgresql` support for JSONField type or [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield/).

Is there currently no way django natively supports mysql's json type. Also while doing `inspectdb` a column of type `json` in mysql was assigned the type `TextField` with a comment `This field type is a guess.`

How would I declare my model in such a way that it supports json fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As of Django 3.2, it now supports [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField) and django-mysql JSONField is now deprecated.

---

Check out [django-mysql](http://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html).

Django-MySQL supports the JSON data type and related functions through JSONField plus some JSON database functions.

Comment: does it work along with normal django models, i.e. the ones from django.db?

Comment: Sure, look at the examples.

Answer (score 0):

You've already found `django-jsonfield`, but here are some recent discussions you may be interested in:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/django-developers/mysql$20json%7Csort:relevance/django-developers/zfred27yVPg/U-4iNd_aAQAJ

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/django-developers/mysql$20json%7Csort:relevance/django-developers/sAgYOqBUvgI/aLQH6vx5CAAJ

AFAIK there isn't anything native currently, but people seem interested in developing what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`JSONField is supported on MariaDB 10.2.7+, MySQL 5.7.8+, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and SQLite 3.9.0+ (with the JSON1 extension enabled)`.

Details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField